# C++ plugins for QML : Hiding built-in properties

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a C++ plugin which contains a custom class subclassed from `QNetworkAccessManager`. In that class I have created some custom properties using `Q_PROPERTY` which can be accessed from QML.
These properties are nicely accessible from QML after loading this plugin and importing the module exposed by it, but the problem is that, along with them other built-in properties are also exposed
which I think might cause a problem if the user tries to access and modify it. 
So the question is how to hide these built-in properties from getting exposed to QML ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You can create an adapter (proxy) class that exposes only 'safe' properties, and inject it into QML instead of the original object.

Comment: @Archie, Thanks. Seems that's the only way to go.